# getting coverage "unknown" in badges

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, gitlab, code-coverage, test-coverage

have been trying to show coverage in code coverage badge.  I am getting coverage at CI/CD
--> JOBS section but the coverage is not getting updated in gitlab badges.Following is my gitlab-ci.yml file where I am finding the coverage and saving it in artifacts.

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -ffdx -e node_modules/
  GIT_DEPTH: 10

stages:
  - test

test:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: test
  script:
    - c8 --all  --reporter=text-summary npm run test 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - coverage
```

Configuration -
Test coverage parsing - "Statements\s+:\s(\d+.?\d+)%"

[image]

Comment: In the link config under `Badges`, you have put the badge URL, instead you need to point to your branch, for instance...`http://gitlab.cpm/abcProject/commits/pipeline-test`

Comment: @G.Pillai Already tried , still getting unknown coverage

Comment: Parsing of coverage result may have failed. [Test coverage parsing](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-parsing) explain how to check if coverage output match regex. Coverage result should appear in the pipeline execution report.

Comment: @mpromonet coverage is appearing in pipeline execution report but somehow not adding up in coverage badge

Comment: Did you try to access to the svg directly with https://gitlab.zeniusnet.com/komal/zs-assessment/bagdes/pipeline-test/coverage.svg ? or maybe https://gitlab.zeniusnet.com/komal/zs-assessment/bagdes/master/coverage.svg ? depending on your branch name.

Comment: it just doesn't work properly and doesn't display nor log expected stuff